# How clip a Grid in the shape of Star Path in silverlight c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `Grid` & `Star` shaped `Path`.

```
 <Path x:Name="StarPath" Data="M213,135 L183,213 L87,246 L159,288 C159,288 140,372 140,375 C140,378 226,329 226,329 L303,367 L280,275 L316,216 L246,219" Fill="#FF0EB679" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="241.132" Margin="86.5,134.5,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230"/>
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300"  Width="300" Background="#FFD11010"/> <br/><br/>
```

I am trying to get my `Grid in the shape of Star shaped Path`. 
Can anybody  provide me any hint or sample for `Clipping Grid by Path by Code` ?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/cropping-or-clipping-in-silverlight/ This shows how to do it with XAML shapes; if you want to do it by C# code, you can access the `UIElement.Clip` property and do it there.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair thanks. But am looking for clipping by Path ; If you can provide me a sample snippet [Clipping UIElement By Path ] that might be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adapt [this méthod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396500/convert-a-silverlight-text-to-a-path)...

`MyGrid.Clip = getPathGeometry(StarPath.Data.ToString());`

You have to add "||" in if test, and change the data.replace by `data = data.Replace("M", " M").Replace("C", " C").Replace("L", " L");`

Comment: i tried it ; but still has an error " "Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PathGeometry' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RectangleGeometry'" . Please note that am working on silverlight for windows phone .

Comment: `PathGeometry` is type of `Geometry` if i read doc :
PathGeometry => Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0... (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry(v=vs.95).aspx). What is the type of `Clip` ?